# Azure Application Insights IPv6 only Pingtest

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a self hosted website which is only available over IPv6. I wanted to create a ping test in Application Insights to get notified if the website goes offline but the ping test fails to resolve the DNS entry. This is most likely because the website does not have a 'A' record but only a 'AAAA' record. Has anyone been able to set up a ping test for this kind of setup?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Felix